# How to capture success on Paypal's Smart Checkout and return a Serial Key?

Tags: php, paypal

### Introduction

Hello I'm going to sell a software using serial keys. Any person can go into my webpage and click on the paypal button to buy a serial key, they don't need to register.

### What I'm trying to achieve

I need to let any person use the button and receive a serial key when the payment is done.

So the workflow would be something like:

1. Any person (non-registered) clicks on the button.
2. The paypal page shows up.
3. The user pays and gets redirected to a page that shows something like "Congratulations, here is your serial key: {{serialKey}}" and also receives the same serialKey via email.

### What I tried

I'm trying to use Paypal's Smart Checkout but I don't understand how to implement what I need.

Right now I'm able to:

- Render the button.
- The button performs a request to my back to get the price (so the user can't change it and trick me).
- The paypal page shows up.
- On success it performs a request to my back.
- On failure it restarts.

What I'm missing:

- How can I check that the payment did actually succeed on the back, I mean that I received the money? Is there any way that I can post to paypal using the ID and see if I that transaction was correct?

---

### Additional question

Is this the right approach? All I need is to let anyone click the button, pay and receive a serial key ONLY if the payment was correct. Right now it seems too complex for what I need. I don't understand everything I see on the paypal docs, if you follow it line by line the examples don't work, you have to adapt a lot of the code and I'm not sure about what I'm doing.

I also read IPN's docs but using it I won't be able to redirect the user because everything would be done in the back without the user even knowing what is happening.

### Final text

Any help is appreciated. I'm asking here because I saw a lot of another questions about paypal like this one that were upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most robust approach is to combine the [PayPal Checkout front-end](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) with a [v2/orders backend](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/) for payment setup and capture.

- [create order](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/)
- [capture order](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/)

This way the capture happens from your server, so you have an immediate success/failure API response -- and can immediately do whatever you need to do to handle the business logic of the digital good purchase (serial key activation/distribution)

---

Once you have everything working well for the happy path, don't neglect to [handle funding source failures](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/), so that if the capture fails due to e.g. the buyer's first card being declined, this is propagated back to the UI and the buyer can select a different funding source.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answering, I'm having problems with the docs because every example they give is broken. Even the demo is broken, it's getting too hard to implement. Do you know if there are better examples posted by someone or better information?

Comment: The demo is not broken, it has placeholder information for the backend endpoints.  It requires a server that implements a v2/orders API call to create the order and return the orderID so that the checkout can proceed.

Comment: But isn't it supposed to work to show how the demo works? That is the same problem I get when using the examples they give on their docs, the data returned is not in the format that the front expects

Comment: The demo shows how the font-end works. It needs a back-end to connect to.  If you want to see a demo that does not require a back-end, see the client-side integration version: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: I understand that. But I thought they would add a simple backend to show how the server side integration works because using the examples from the docs doesn't work. That's why I'm so lost about how to do it. I followed the docs for the server side transaction creation and I had to change A LOT of the code to make it work. Their example returns an object that is not what the front expects.

Comment: Anyway, let's ignore that part. I misunderstood the demo. 1 question about "capture order", I'm a little confused about the "capture order" part, I see it says "capture transaction funds" but what I need is to get the transaction details and I found this: [Get Transaction Details](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/get-transaction/). Is "capture order" another way to get the details of the transaction? or is it to "get the funds"?

Comment: ...Sure, your server is essentially middleware that needs to process the PayPal API response, runs any necessary business logic, and return just the orderID or whatever other particular piece of data the front expects.  Your server is not meant to be a simple proxy for the PayPal API, that would be pointless.

Comment: The capture order part takes an order ID that was approved by the customer, and tells the PayPal API to turn it into an actual PayPal transaction. You receive the transaction details in the response, which is a v2/payments object (different from the v2/orders object you started with, which is for approval purposes)

Comment: What would be the difference between doing "capture order" and "get transaction details" I mean, both would work right? I would get the payment, and when doing the request on both cases I would get if it was approved or not. Is the "turn it into an actual paypal transaction" part needed?

Comment: Absolutely, it's the most critical moment of truth. There is no financial transaction if you don't capture an order -- nothing gets sent to a card or bank or financial institution for processing. The customer has merely given their approval.  If you "get the details" of an order w/o a capture, it will simply reflect this approval.  You can't "get transaction details" before capture, because there is no transaction.

Comment: Oh, thank god I asked here. I don't know if I'm stupid but I find the paypal docs so confusing. Thank you for all your help